# How to make my JAR library to be included in the <uses-library> in AndroidManifest.xml and use it as a shared library

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I have my own jar library, but it is been used by multiple applications 
How to make my JAR library to be included in the  in AndroidManifest.xml and use it as a shared library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<uses-library>` is for libraries that are part of device firmware (SDK add-ons). So, unless you are distributing your own hardware or ROM mods, `<uses-library>` will not be of use to you.

Moreover, generally speaking, you *want* to have independent copies of that library, one per app using it. That way, you can update each app separately. Otherwise, changes to your JAR may necessitate simultaneous changes to all of your apps, and since you are not in charge of installing those app updates (users are), that could be a major problem.